# Number-Character mapping in Haskell with list comprehension

Tags: haskell

I have a simple function in Haskell that takes a list of tuples like this: `[(1,'a'),(2,'b')..(26,'z')]`, and returns a letter value based on the number input.  So ideally,

```
getCharByNum 3
> "c"
```

I'm attempting this by using a list comprehension, and filtering out every tuple that doesn't contain that number.

```
zippedChars = zip [ x | x <- [1..26]]  [ x | x <- ['a'..'z']]
getCharByNum :: (Integral a) => a -> [Char]
getCharByNum num = [ head vector | vector <- zippedChars, num == last vector ]
```

I think this makes sense...getCharByNum is a function that takes an Integer, and returns a (short) list of Chars.  But GHCI throws this error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `[a]'
            with actual type `(Integer, Char)'
In the first argument of `last', namely `vector'
In the second argument of `(==)', namely `last vector'
In the expression: num == last vector
```

How do you correctly construct a type signature that allows this function to run?  (I know that this can be easily done with an index, or even more easily with Data.Char.ord, but I'm trying to understand list comprehensions better)

EDIT: I've cleaned the code a bit:

```
zippedChars = zip [1..26] ['a'..'z']
getCharByNum :: Integral -> [Char]
getCharByNum num = [ c | (n,c) <- zippedChars, num == n ]
```

But I am still getting this error:

```
folds.hs:50:18:
    Expecting one more argument to `Integral'
    In the type signature for `getCharByNum':
      getCharByNum :: (Integral) -> [Char]
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

This is a function that takes one Integer and returns a list of Chars, so I am not sure what I am missing.

Comment: The function you are trying to implement is `lookup`. You can also implement it (approximately) as `\i d -> [(k,v) | (k,v) <- d, k == i]`. This says "take all the key,value pairs in d such that the key is equal to the given search key, and yield that key,value pair". Your function doesn't work in part because `head` and `tail` operate on *lists* and tuples (things like `(1, 'a')`) are *not* lists. For tuples, you should use fst and snd, or better yet, pattern matching.

Comment: If you have trouble getting a type signature right, try leaving it out, and then ask GHCi (in this case, with `:t getCharByNum`) what it infers the type to be.

Comment: BTW, the somehow "standard" implementation for this is to use `fromEnum/toEnum` to convert to integer and back, and add the offset in the meanwhile. There's no need of building a lookup table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integral is a typeclass. Integral is not a type. a is an instance of Integral, so we declare this at the beginning of the signature.

```
zippedChars :: Integral a => [(a, Char)]
zippedChars = zip [1..26] ['a'..'z']

getCharByNum :: Integral a => a -> String
getCharByNum num = [ c | (n,c) <- zippedChars, num == n ]

>>> getCharByNum 3
'c'
```

A suggestion:

```
>>> ['a'..'z'] !! 4
'c'
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you are using `head` and `last`, which apply to lists only, while your `vector` is a tuple.  You need to use `fst` and `snd` instead.  Or even better, you can use pattern matching:

```
getCharByNum num = [ c | (n,c) <- zippedChars, num == n ]
```

By the way, `[ x | x <- [1..26]]` is the same as just `[1..26]`, and similarly for the character list.

Comment: Yes, pattern matching and the range are much a much better way to do this.  I am still struggling with the Type Signature though.